# Calculating wheel velocities for differentail drive.

Tags: robotics

I really want to know how to determine formulas for velocity in a differential drive?
I found these formulas that work for me:

$$v_r = \frac{(2 \cdot v) + (w \cdot L)}{2 \cdot R}$$
$$v_l = \frac{(2 \cdot v) - (w \cdot L)}{2 \cdot R}$$
But even knowing kinematics of differentail robot, I don't know how to solve this to achive velocity foreach wheel.
Here is kinematics:
[differential drive](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node659.html)
[unicycle model](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node660.html#fig:unicycle)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

This is a consequence of the Euler-Poisson kinematic law for a rigid body.

$$
\vec v_1 = \vec v_2 + \vec \omega \times (p_1-p_2)
$$

Here $p_1, p_2$ are the wheel floor contact points.